# Returning the nearest multiple value of a number

Tags: c#

I need a function by which I will be able to convert a number to a nearest value of a given multiple.

Eg i want an array of number to be set to the neareast multiple of 16, so 2 = 0, 5 = 0, 11 = 16, 17 = 16, 30 = 32 etc

thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Some division and rounding should be all you need for this:

```
int value = 30;
int factor = 16;
int nearestMultiple = 
        (int)Math.Round(
             (value / (double)factor),
             MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
         ) * factor;
```

Be careful using this technique. The `Math.Round(double)` overload believes the evil mutant `MidpointRounding.ToEven` is the best default behavior, even though what we all learned before in school is what the CLR calls `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`. For example:

```
var x = Math.Round(1.5); // x is 2.0, like you'd expect
x = Math.Round(0.5); // x is 0. WAT?!
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a solution to my problem for a week.

Comment: `MidpointRounding.ToEven` is used so that on average rounding error will shift the value upwards about as much as it goes down. Always going away from zero means that over many calculations error would gradually compound error until your values where very far off. But yeah, it's not what  you'd usually want for calculating a final display value.

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to do any floating point division, it's unnecessary. Use the remainder operator:

```
int rem = val % multiple;
int result = val - rem;
if (rem >= (multiple / 2))
    result += multiple;
```

Comment: As I'm otherwise unfamiliar with "round to even", wanted to note to the above that it rounds down on even.  Converting it to round up in all cases (as I believe most people would otherwise expect), change the conditional from > to >=

Comment: This should really be the best answer. I think this even avoids loss of precision with doubles and floating point, as division by 2 generally shouldn't be a problem (I may be wrong though)

Answer (score 9):

`16*((n+8)/16)` is the formula you want if, in particular, you want to convert 8 to 16 (it's equally close to 0 as to 16, so it's impossible to decide how to convert it based exclusively on the "nearest multiple" concept, you have to decide!-), and of course consistently 24 to 32, 40 to 48, and so forth.  Use `+7` in lieu of `+8` if you'd rather convert 8 to 0 rather than to 16 (and consistently 24 to 16, and so forth).

To use a generic `X` in lieu of the hardcoded `16`, then the formula is `X*((n+X/2)/X)` (with the same proviso as in the above paragraph if `X` is even).

**Edit**: no need to mess around with floating point numbers as other answers suggest, but you *do* need to multiply back by `X` (which I had erroneously omitted).

Comment: (n+8)/16 does not work. try, say 11. (11+8)/16 = 19/16. I think you're relying on dividing truncating here, so 19/16 = 1. but 11 should round to 16. So you still need to multiply by 16 to get the correct answer.

Comment: @wallacolo, you're right -- I forgot to multiply back -- editing to fix.

Comment: This should be the top answer, as it simple and requires neither floating point operations nor conditions, only integer division and multiplication.
Besides, it does "round up to next multiple" with little change, namely `16*((n+15)/16)` (which I would rewrite to `(n+15)/16*16`).
You should probably use the generalized form, i.e. `(n+m/2)/m*m)`, though.

Answer (score 5):

In case of rounding of to the nearest multiple of a float, you can use this:

```
public static float convert(float value, float multipleOf) 
{
    return (float) Math.Round((decimal)value / (decimal)multipleOf, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * multipleOf;
}
```

Then you can use the function like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Convert 10.723: " + convert(10.723f, 0.5f)); // 10.5
```

Answer (score 2):

The case is a bit more complicated if the multiple is less than 1. I wrote this general function:

```
public float NearestRound(float x, float delX)
{
    if (delX < 1)
    {
        float i = (float)Math.Floor(x);
        float x2 = i;
        while ((x2 += delX) < x) ;
        float x1 = x2 - delX;
        return (Math.Abs(x - x1) < Math.Abs(x - x2)) ? x1 : x2;
    }
    else {
        return (float)Math.Round(x / delX, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * delX;
    }
}

/* Sample:
x: 101 multiple:2 NearestRound -> 102
x: 107 multiple:2 NearestRound -> 108
x: 100.9 multiple:2 NearestRound -> 100
x: 1 multiple:0.25 NearestRound -> 1
x: 1.35 multiple:0.25 NearestRound -> 1.25
x: 1.77 multiple:0.25 NearestRound -> 1.75
x: 1.9 multiple:0.25 NearestRound -> 2 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Rounds the middle towards +∞

```
int RoundNearest16(int value)
{
    return (value + 8) & ~0xF;
}
```

Comment: how about other numbers? for example 5

Comment: It looks cool, but all I know is that "0xF" is a hexadecimal code. Need a explain