# How do I round a float to the nearest multiple of n?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, rounding

I have a float.  I want to round it to the nearest multiple of n, where n is any float.  How can I do this?

In my particular instance, I need my float to be a multiple of 0.96f, but 0.96f is subject to change.

For example, if I have 1.0f, I want to get 0.96f.  Or if I have 1.75f, I want to get 1.92f.  I do not need to account for negative numbers, although it would be good if it did.

I have checked the other questions about rounding, but they are all in powers of 2.  (0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, etc.)

Comment: can you provide examples so we are clear on your requirements?

Comment: In general, use `ROUND(x/n)*n`

Comment: I marked a duplicate that's in Java, but the premise is the same.  Note also that you can use whichever of the various rounding options (`AwayFromZero`, `ToEven`) are appropriate.

Comment: For `float` you just need type casting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705542/returning-the-nearest-multiple-value-of-a-number/47176199#47176199

Answer (score 8):

Divide your input (`n`) by the number you're rounding to (`x`), round that, and multiply that back with `x` and that's your result!

```
double RoundToNearest(double n, double x) {
    return round(n / x) * x;
}
```