How do you round up to the nearest 1000
I have this code:
int rounded = ((int)Math.Round(maxPriceDecimal));

So lets say for example maxPriceDecimal is 1100 or 1400, what i need is the value to round to 2000.
Or if maxPriceDecimal is 10200, i would need the rounded to equal 11000.
How would i solve this?

Also check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705542/returning-the-nearest-multiple-value-of-a-number

What do you want to occur if the value is -1100? If it is 1999? 2000? 2001?

the values will be all positive, if its value 1999 the rounded to 2000 and if value is 2001 the rounded would be 3000, so the value is always rounded up to a 1000.

Look at Math.Ceiling.

int rounded = (int)(Math.Ceiling(maxPriceDecimal / 1000.0) * 1000);
try this
